# How to check if the thousandth decimal place isn't 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a MS SQL Server database which is of type `Decimal(10,6)`.

I have some scenarios where I'd like the number to simply be .xx0000.

How do I check if the thousandth (and beyond) decimal place isn't 0?

A few examples:

- **1.123456** should match the query
- **1.120000** shouldn't match the query
- **1.000000** shouldn't match the query
- **1.000001** should match the query

Comment: select * from yourtable where somecolumn * 1000000 % 10000 > 0

Comment: this smells like an XY problem.

Comment: @MitchWheat, yes, but at least it's not a float column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some scenarios where I'd like the number to simply be .xx0000.
>
> How do I check if the thousandth (and beyond) decimal place isn't 0?

Multiply the number by 100. Then your query becomes "The number is (not) xx.000", which means "the number is (not) integer", or rather "is (not) equal to its floor value".

```
WHERE (number*100) != FLOOR(number*100)
```

Nothing strange happens in the above scenario due to the `DECIMAL` [representation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) (which I checked for MySQL, but [it seems to hold for MS SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) too up to 17 digits of precision): even if *number* is at the storage limit for its data type, the server will silently "upgrade" its DECIMAL storage space to accommodate the result of the multiplication. So, multiplying 9999.000012 by 1000 will yield a `DECIMAL(14,6)` value, which can be compared with no loss.

In other scenarios with **floating point** values (or where the server does not realize it's dealing with DECIMAL numbers and introduces floating points, or you make a "small change" in the formula and introduce those yourself), the above might yield a false positive when it so happens that "number*100" *is not equal* to 100 times number due to [floating point representation](https://www.itu.dk/%7Esestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf), i.e. (I made up this example, using a much larger "effect")

```
n     = 12.6389998  // This matches...
n*100 = 1263.90000  // ...but this no longer does
```

A different, but equally bad thing would happen if you cast the multiplication result, but only when you got an overflow (so it might seem to work with smaller numbers, only to break every once in a while):

```
WHERE CAST(number*100 AS DECIMAL(10,6)) != FLOOR(CAST(number*100 AS DECIMAL(10,6))
```

So, a more awkward possibility would be to cast the number as a string (which is, as far as I know, exact; or rather, keeps the same approximation in the number and in the string), then verify whether it is `LIKE '%000'` through a string operation.

Comment: @DaleK ...I have been having some eye troubles. I had read 'MySQL Server' :-( . However, the CAST syntax is similar and what I could find on automatic precision upgrade seems to be the same (or rather, I suspect that SQL mandates this kind of operation and both MS SQL and MySQL complied).

Answer (score 3):

You can multiply it by 1000 and mod it, like so:

```
CAST(replace_me * 1000 AS INT) % 1000 <> 0;
```

Comment: That doesn't work for 1.000123

Comment: yeah just spotted that :(

Comment: Please **never do this**. If you do it with `DECIMAL(10,6)`, r * 1000 might overflow its 10,6 storage space: for example `CAST(99.999 * 1000 AS DECIMAL(10,6))` will yield not 99999 but 9999,999999 -- with the consequences you can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought was in line with what others have posted (more or less "take mantissa, multiply by a million, and check result mod 10"), but here's a different approach:

```sql
select a,
    [SubtractTruncated] = a - cast(a as decimal(18,5)),
    [MantissaMod] = (1000000 * ( a - cast(a as int) ) ) % 10
from (values
    ( cast(1.123456 as decimal(18, 6)) ),
    ( cast(1.120000 as decimal(18, 6)) ),
    ( cast(1.000000 as decimal(18, 6)) ),
    ( cast(1.000001 as decimal(18, 6)) )
) as x(a);
```

Casting the value as one lower scale will do some sort of rounding (either up or down) in the case where the desired check digit is anything but a zero. Subtracting that from the original value will produce a value of zero iff the original value had a zero in it's least significant digit.

I've also included a variation on the approach that others have used for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just cast them as varchar and use like?

```sql
select * from table where cast(fieldname as varchar(16)) not like '%0000'
```